# How to show number of rows and number of groups for data frames in html output of Rmd file?

Tags: html, r, dataframe, r-markdown

If I write this in an .Rmd file chunk in RStudio

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(var)
```

and then I run the chunk, the output will have

```
A tibble: 789542 x 8 Groups: var[8]
```

on top on the printed data frame.

I find these information very useful and I would like to have them also in the html document I knit this .Rmd file into but for now I have been unsuccessful.

I tried all the options for

```
output:
  html_document:
    df_print:
```

them being paged, tibble, kable and kable-scroll.

I don't know if there are some more or if you can tweak them with optional arguments, extensive google searches led to nothing.
I wouldn't know how to start to write a custom function.

I also tried `DT:::datatable()` but it only shows the number of rows, and not the groups.

I know I can pipe additional `nrow()` and `n_groups()` to each df, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

This html document will be presented in a very simple github page.
I know blogdown/hugo and the new Quarto are more powerful and maybe they offer a solution but I don't know if I wanna learn how to use them (I've heard they are much more complicated) for this little project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the `tibble` information (number of row x columns and group information) along with paged output, we can write a custom function by modifying the [`print.paged_df`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/main/R/html_paged.R#L241-L248) function (which is used internally by rmarkdown for the `df_print` feature) and use CSS to nicely format the output.

````markdown
---
title: "Showing data group info"
output: html_document
---

# R markdown

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, df_print="info_paged")
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
info_paged_print <- function(x, options) {
  tibble_info <- paste0("<div class=\"tibble-info\">A tibble: ", nrow(x), " x ", ncol(x), "</div>")
  group_info <- paste0("<div class=\"group-info\">Groups: ", 
                      paste0(group_vars(x), collapse = ", "), 
                      " [", nrow(group_keys(x)), "]", "</div>")
  
  if (dplyr::is_grouped_df(x)) {
    tab_info <- paste0("<div class=\"info\">", tibble_info, " ", group_info, "</div>")
    cat(tab_info)
  } else {
    cat(paste0("<div class=\"info\">", tibble_info, "</div>"))
  }
  knitr::asis_output(
    rmarkdown:::paged_table_html(x, options = attr(x, "options")),
    meta = list(
      dependencies = rmarkdown:::html_dependency_pagedtable()
    )
  )
}

knitr::opts_hooks$set(df_print = function(options) {
  if (options$df_print == "info_paged") {
    options$render = info_paged_print
    options$comment = ""
    options$results = "asis"
  }
  options
})
```

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.tibble-info,
.group-info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.info {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #999898;
}
```


```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=""}
library(dplyr)
```

## Grouped Data

```{r}
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am, vs)
```

## Ungrouped Data

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```


## logical filtering

```{r}
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    logical = if_else(mpg > mean(mpg), TRUE, FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  filter(logical)
```
````

---

[image: tibble and group info with paged output]

---

And you can tweak the CSS to render the `tibble` information as you like.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I appreciate it, and apologies that I forgot to mention that I know about that solution, that I ruled out because it looks kinda ugly plus it doesn't permit to navigate through the rows of the data frame like the paged option does.

Comment: Yes you should have been mentioned that in your question. Now it makes my answer completely useless.

Comment: @goingdeep, I have completely updated my answer.

Comment: thanks @shafee, it was very kind of you. I receive an error if I pipe a filter() on a logical column though, like filter(LogicalColumn). It states "Error in UseMethod("group_vars"): no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "logical" Calls :<Anonymous> ... withVisible -> value_fun -> fun -> paste0 -> paste0 -> group_vars.

Comment: don't worry about fixing it though, you already went above and beyond and I can't ask you to fix every little bug I may encounter, as there are some advanced dplyr pipes in this project so it could be an endless task for you.

Comment: @goingdeep, Can you paste the code from which the above error is generated?

Comment: df %>% mutate(LogicalColumn = if_else(Var == "Value", TRUE, FALSE)) %>% filter(LogicalColumn)

Comment: I am not getting any errors and I have updated my answer to show that your case is working for me. And if this answer helps you, you should upvote it and accept it : )

Comment: thanks for the implication and yes, the error was caused instead by lines like '2 == 2'. I solved it by adding 'df_print = "paged" in the chunk options. Answer upvoted and accepted :)

Comment: There are two other "issues" now, one is that I would like to show also when a data frame is rowwise, for when I use 'rowwise()' or 'nest_by().' I will try to modify your code and in case of failure I will open another question. 'group_split()' and 'group_walk()' are two other tricky functions, I have to reflect more on those.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate this with the use of a simple custom function. The output is not exactly the same but it may be able to fit your needs.

Below is the demonstration using the mtcars dataset and the column of "cyl".

```
PrintSummary <- function(df, col){
  
  Line1 <- paste0("A tibble: ", nrow(df), " x ", ncol(df))
  Line2 <- paste0("Groups: ", col, "[", length(unique(df[, col])), "]")
  
  message(Line1)
  message(Line2)
  
}

PrintSummary(mtcars, "cyl")
```

The output should be the following:

```
A tibble: 32 x 11
Groups: cyl[3]
```

Comment: thanks to you as well, do you think it would be possible to have a default for col for when the data frame is not grouped?

Comment: You are welcome! I am afraid I do not know of such default options. What you can do, however, is to add attribute (stating which is the col for grouping) to the data.frame, then modify the function to look for the data.frame attribute if col is not specified.

Comment: thanks again for the answer, I will use shafee solution but I value yours as well as I can surely learn something from it.